# bitnami magento 2 stack accessing magento setup

Tags: magento2, bitnami

How do I access the magento setup files in a VM using bitnami linux debian ?

my VM box is 192.168.1.12

would it be 192.168.1.12/magento    ?

browsing to 192.168.1.12 shows

"It Works!" so I know apache is working, the myphpadmin works, the database is there.

192.168.1.12/magento shows

But I am not sure how to get magento started, its possible I screwed up something, just wondering if anyone can confirm how you browse to the magento install.

Maybe I have to run a script to install it and its alias first? But everything else is done, so I must be way off track.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Something must have been screwed up, just entering the machine IP brought me to the magento home page when I downloaded a new updated appliance from bitnami. Thanks bitnami impressive. Maybe another clue that I would have trouble would have been the 10.0.0.21 IP address that originally showed up, also the new appliance showed a bridged network connection, the other did not I had to change it, so maybe that should be set first?